# Longest substring with unique characters

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, unit-testing, comparative-review

> Find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters

Any comments on my code?

```
public class LongestSubstring {
    /**
     * First version. O(n^2) runtime
     * For each character, find the longest substring starting
     * with this character and update max
     * @param s
     * @return
     */
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstringV1(String s) {
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        int n = c.length;
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            // localMax is the size of the longest substring starting with character i
            // and that has no repeated character
            int localMax = findLocalMax(c,i);
            // update max if localMax > max
            max = (max > localMax) ? max : localMax;
        }
        return max;
    }

    /**
     * find the largest substring that has no repeated character
     * starting at character i in array c
     * @param c
     * @param i
     * @return
     */
    public int findLocalMax(char[] c, int i){
        int n = c.length;
        // seen: characters already seen
        HashSet<Character> seen = new HashSet<Character>();
        int localMax = 0;

        for (int j = i; j < n; j++){
            // c[j] was seen already
            if (seen.contains(c[j])){
                return localMax;
            }
            else{
                seen.add(c[j]);
                localMax++;
            }
        }
        return localMax;
    }

    /**
     * Second version. O(n^2) runtime
     * if a character is seen again,
     * @param s
     * @return
     */
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstringV2(String s) {
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        int n = c.length;
        // currentLetters: HashSet of the letters contained in the current substring
        HashSet<Character> currentLetters = new HashSet<Character>();
        // pointer1 points to the beginning of the substring
        int pointer1 = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int currentCount = 0;

        // pointer2 points to the end of the substring
        for (int pointer2 = 0; pointer2 < n; pointer2++){
            if (currentLetters.contains(c[pointer2])){
                // if the letter c[pointer2] has already been seen
                // remove all the letters before the first occurrence
                // of this letter to consider the substring beginning after
                // this first occurrence
                while (c[pointer1] != c[pointer2]){
                    currentCount--;
                    currentLetters.remove(c[pointer1]);
                    pointer1++;
                }
            }
            else{
                // otherwise, add the letter to the substring
                currentCount++;
                currentLetters.add(c[pointer2]);
            }
            max = (max > currentCount) ? max : currentCount;
        }

        return max;
    }
}

public class TestLongestSubstring {
    LongestSubstring lgs = new LongestSubstring();
    @Test
    public void testEmptyString(){
        String s = "";
        assertEquals(0,lgs.lengthOfLongestSubstringV1(s));
        assertEquals(0,lgs.lengthOfLongestSubstringV2(s));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSameCharacterExpects1(){
        String s = "bbbb";
        assertEquals(1,lgs.lengthOfLongestSubstringV1(s));
        assertEquals(1,lgs.lengthOfLongestSubstringV2(s));
    }

    @Test
    public void testabcabcbbExpects3(){
        String s = "abcabcbb";
        assertEquals(3,lgs.lengthOfLongestSubstringV1(s));
        assertEquals(3,lgs.lengthOfLongestSubstringV2(s));
    }
}


public class TestLongestSubstringRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestLongestSubstring.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()){
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Time complexity

The time complexity is not \$O(N^2)\$ as you estimated, but actually \$O(N M)\$, where n is the length of the input string and m is the number of unique characters in the input string. This makes a big difference, because in practice m is typically bounded by a constant, the size of the alphabet, which in the case of ascii is 256. If m is a constant then the asymptotic complexity becomes simply \$O(N)\$, which is great news for you.

#### Optimizations

A small tweak can make the implementation significantly faster: change the loop condition in the outer function to go until `n - max` instead of n.

If you know the size of the alphabet in advance, then you can use a `boolean[]` instead of a set, with the character codes as indexes. It's simpler, and by reducing the autoboxing, faster too.

#### Use interface types instead of implementations

You could declare the `HashSet` as a `Set` instead.

Answer (score 5):

### Naming :

While it's so easy to give short naming to variable, it's just bad practice.

- String s
- char c
- int n

These are examples of what it shouldn't be.  It should be replaced so you know just by reading it what the var is coming from.
Example:
`String s` could be `String inputString`.

### Clear javadoc:

Actually "Find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters" does tell me more then the javadoc of  `public int lengthOfLongestSubstringV1(String s)`
Why? 
In your javadoc there is no mentioning about the absence of repeating characters.

### Comments:

While code should be self explaining, sometimes it's good to put a comment.
This example is not so good:

```
// seen: characters already seen
HashSet<Character> seen = new HashSet<Character>();
```

The comment is there because you think that the person who reads your code will not understand what the `HashSet` is for.
Maybe it's the naming of the var why you did this?
Otherwise, there is no reason to say what it holds.

### Variable to much, using set correct:

```
public int findLocalMax(char[] c, int i)
```

This method contains `int localMax`.
There is no reason to have this variable and counting them up, you just can return the size of your `Set`.
Actually I should rewrite this whole operation to :

```
public int findLocalMax(char[] c, int position) {
    int arrayLenght = c.length;
    HashSet<Character> charsSeen = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (int pointer = position; pointer < arrayLenght; pointer++){
        if (!charsSeen.add(c[pointer])){
            break;
        }
    }
    return charsSeen.size();
}
```

Explication : A set can't have duplicates, so if you try to insert a duplicated value, this would not be done and the `add` method will return false.
In fact, with your code you could even use a `List`.
So if this fails, you know it's time to break the for loop and return the result, the `charsSeen` his size.

I'm not the greatest mathematician so I'm not reviewing your mathematical solution, only improving your current solution to cleaner code.

### Again early returns:

In the `lengthOfLongestSubstringV1` there is just one thing what could be simple to improve.
Think of this your test case : "abcabcbb".
If your pointer is at the last "c" => your max result is 3.
The last c could only be max 3 long because you don't have more characters.
Why bother checking them?

So again, I would update the method to this :

```
  public int lengthOfLongestSubstringV1(String inputString) {
    char[] inputCharArray = inputString.toCharArray();
    int charArrayLength = inputCharArray.length;
    int currentMaxLength = 0;

    for (int pointer = 0; pointer < charArrayLength; pointer++){
        int localMax = findLocalMax(inputCharArray,pointer);
        currentMaxLength = (currentMaxLength > localMax) ? currentMaxLength : localMax;
        if (currentMaxLength >= charArrayLength - pointer) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return currentMaxLength;
}
```

Hope this helps.